# Spring Integration message-driven-channel-adapter tag not honoring bean name?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I'm using Spring Integration 4.0.3.RELEASE and Spring Framework 4.0.2.RELEASE.

I have the following Spring Integration code in my context file:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="exchangeQueueChannelAdapter" 
auto-startup="true"
destination="exchangeQueueJmsDestination"
channel="exchangeSpringQueueChannel"
receive-timeout="1000"
connection-factory="WMQCachedConnectionFactory"
acknowledge="transacted"
transaction-manager="WMQTxManager"
error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

Notice that I've given the bean being created a name [exchangeQueueChannelAdapter].
When exceptions occur within the underlying `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` however it doesn't appear like the Spring Integration tags are passing the beanName to the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` class.  This results in an exception looking like this (notice the thread name):

```
[org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] WARN  (org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue://CDCS.F370ZZZ.TRADOUT.FIXML' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] ERROR (org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'citi.cibtech.na.ExPro_149155.DERIVS_ETD_TRD.TMG_CONTROLBUS.T1' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Looking at the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` code, it appears that it would prepend the beanName to the front of the threadname if it were passed into the class when it's initialized.

```
protected TaskExecutor createDefaultTaskExecutor() {
  String beanName = getBeanName();
  String threadNamePrefix = (beanName != null ? beanName + "-" : DEFAULT_THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
  return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(threadNamePrefix);
}
```

Ideally I'd like a way to be able to get the thread to have my bean name somewhere in the name of the thead (i.e. "exchangeQueueChannelAdapter#0-1").  Is there a way to do that without having to create a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` on my own?  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an external `TaskExecutor` with a custom name and the threads will be named that way...

```
<task:executor id="foo" />
```

Threads will be named "foo-n"

Provide it to the adapter using the `task-executor` attribute.